# outlook for mac - wrong date on the sent items

Tags: ms-office

I have a problem using outlook for mac 2011, after I imported my emails, the sent items shows wrong date, When i open the message, it shows the right date, how can I fix it? i want to show the right date when i view the message and I open the message. tried to repair the identity but it didn't worked

thank you

Comment: What are the actual dates (and times)?

Comment: the actual dates is the date that i sent the message to a recipient which was  Dec 9 2011 and the view date is 4 feb 2013,i really don't know why its showing as 4 feb 2013 this happened after i imported my identity back to my outlook

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned below :

- Create a new identity to remove database issues
- Check your folder’s arrangement and system settings

To create a new user, the predefined path is :

Go to System Preferences --> Create a New User in Accounts.

Then Switch to the New User by logging out/in or you can try user Switching option.

If you still face this issue then problem exists into folders i.e. associated with Outlook Mac backup file.